# Is there any plan to bring dark mode to MSE as in the case of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, dark-mode

Recently, dark mode has been applied on https://stackoverflow.com.

[image]

The result is fantastic to me. Is there any plan to bring it to MSE?

Comment: God, I hope so.

Comment: This post on [meta.se] was bumped today: [Dark Mode for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111399).

Comment: To be honest, this looks really horrible. The blue question title on dark background hurts/strain my eye even more than black text on bright white background. At the least, the dark mode need to make a better choice for text colors.

Comment: All of the problems boil down to which color for which element :)

Comment: @achillehui I agree. I usually like dark mode, but SO's dark mode is kinda gross.

Comment: I have never realized how much I wanted dark mode... on the mobile app!

Comment: I hope it comes!

Comment: In the meantime, you can install the extension [DarkReader](https://darkreader.org/) on many browsers. It works well on many mainstream website and it is customizable. [Here](https://i.imgur.com/xLsfAY8.png) is a screenshot on my computer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion @GabrielRomon :)))

Comment: I should add that Dark Reader has been the target of some malicious activity -- copies of it, executing malicious code, are available for most major browsers. If you download it, make sure to get the legitimate one! More information on [Dark Reader's blog](https://darkreader.org/blog/attention/)

Comment: @Crush_on_You I hope for this feature too.

Comment: @Crush_on_You I hope for this feature too.

Comment: Just put it up anyone wants it, he'll have it and the rest enjoy!

Comment: My eyes hurt...

Comment: Mine as well @pshmath0

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It would *appear* that it is not: [Introducing Dark Mode (beta) for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/30/introducing-dark-mode-for-stack-overflow/?cb=1).

> There are a lot of challenges to implementing dark mode across a platform like ours. We are among the 40 largest websites in the world in terms of monthly unique visitors. We also have hundreds of communities with different design aesthetics. On top of our public Q&A platform, we also have our developer profiles, job listings, product pages, and many other surfaces.
>
> Despite the challenges, this opportunity was too big to be ignored. Today [30 March 2020], we are proud to announce the release of Dark Mode in beta for Stack Overflow. We want to share it with our community, especially our power users, and gather feedback so we can improve, iterate, and expand Dark Mode in the future. You can opt-in Dark Mode through your user preferences. You must be logged into your Stack Overflow account to get this option.
>
> For now, we have no plans to bring dark mode to the many sites across the Stack Exchange network. Many of the designs on our sites have been around long enough that converting them to dark mode would require redoing the artwork completely. We would prefer to avoid giving anyone across our network a substandard experience and we don’t want to change those elements without the input of these communities.

*My reading* of the blog post in general *suggests* that they did it because many programmers have Stack Overflow open literally pretty much all day. Programmers often have dark modes for their IDE (integrated development environment) of choice.

This is not the case for other SE sites. Some people may use SE Maths a lot, but it's not open 8hrs per day (except, perhaps, for a small minority).
Even professional mathematicians who would use Maths Stack Exchange a lot (who may well use Math Overflow quite a lot too), they spend a lot of time writing on paper (or similar).

It seems to be that the argument is that the need is much lower for other sites, and they say that there would be significant work in changing them -- cue excuse about "not wanting to give anyone... a substandard experience" to get out of doing it!

Comment: I feel sad to hear so.

Comment: Any amount of staring at an unfiltered white screen is a strain on the eyes. It doesn't have to be for 8 hours.

Comment: Sure, I'm not saying that it would be a _bad_ thing. But it if involved them having to redo all the artwork, etc... maybe better things they could spend their time on? I guess if the Maths SE community wants it, we should make a meta post and get upvoting!

Comment: Oh, er, um : NO!

Comment: While I can see where implementing dark mode on many sites such as SciFi and World-Building, with specialized logos and background would entail a lot of extra effort, that doesn't apply to MSE, whose logo is simpler than Stack Overflow, and which uses pretty much the same basic formatting. The only thing special about MSE formatting is its massive use of mathjax. But i believe mathjax is available on Stack Overflow as well (it certainly is on many other forums), so I suspect that issue has already been addressed. I would love to see dark mode made available to MSE.

Comment: @PaulSinclair You raise valid points. I'm not sure that the use of MathJax is a valid excuse though. I use [Dark Reader](https://darkreader.org/) (after it was suggested by Gabriel Romon in the comments on the OP), and it works absolutely fine on MSE with MathJax

Comment: I should add that Dark Reader has been the target of some malicious activity -- copies of it, executing malicious code, are available for most major browsers. If you download it, make sure to get the legitimate one! More information on [Dark Reader's blog](https://darkreader.org/blog/attention/)

Comment: Just put it up anyone wants it, he'll have it and the rest enjoy!

Comment: Either SE does it for us or we do, I seriously need this feature or I'll be blink in a few years