# Dark theme in MSE

Tags: feature-request, design, dark-mode

I couldn't find whether this question has been already asked and whether this is  really necessary.

Do we have an option to use dark theme in MSE? I am not aware whether MSE offers dark mode. It will be nice if dark mode is available.

Comment: This would be better asked at the  MSE site: [meta.se].  It is a network wide meta, so please try to stick with Math.se or maths.se or mathematics.se.  Currently, it is not available on most sites.  But you can ask if there if there a plans to make it an option elsewhere, as well.

Comment: An older post: [Is there any plan to bring dark mode to MSE as in the case of Stack Overflow?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31421) (As I see that the new tag (dark-mode) was created here, maybe it should be added to that one, too.)

Answer (score 7):

There is already the correct answer that there is currently no native Dark Mode offered by SE for the Mathematics SE (or indeed any SE site). While we wait, I'll just point out that there are browser plugins for e.g. [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions) that allow you to have a (less than perfect) dark mode on pretty much any website. An example screenshot with MathJax:

[image]
Other screenshots: [mathjax on math.meta.SE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zX7e1.png), [the front page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcOVu.png), [Featured on Meta box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HaML.png), [activity page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub8Ug.png), [close votes review queue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Un95k.png), [achievements box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Om1lM.png), [tags on profile page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8eqB.png)

Answer (score 6):

Dark mode is only available for Stack Overflow.

There are pending feature requests and discussions on the main Meta see e.g. [Plans for dark mode for all Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359739/plans-for-dark-mode-for-all-stack-exchange-sites)